# Regex not working when wrapped in single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to wrap a regex in quotes so that I can add another javascript variable into it, but this stops it from working.

Here's the working example...

```
var re = new RegExp(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/);
```

And what I eventually want to achieve will look something like this (but amended so that it works):

```
var re = new RegExp('^'+element.defaultValue+'|(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$');
```

This allows a date formatted DD/MM/YYYY or the default value of the input field.

Comment: Your first piece of code is not totally correct btw. You should pass a string to `RegExp`, not a regex literal. Your code is equivalen to `var re = /^...$/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside a string literal you need to escape all of the backslashes. For example `'\d'` is actually just the string `'d'` because the Javascript parser takes the backslash as the start of a string escape sequence. The `RegExp()` constructor needs actual backslashes in the string so you have to escape them:

```
 `'|(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\\/\\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\\/\\-]\\d{4}$'`
```

If the default value you are trying to put into the string contains any special characters you must escape them also. Either escape them in the `element.defaultValue` or use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You need to *not* escape the slash, but *do* escape the backslash:

`new RegExp('^'+element.defaultValue+'|(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/\\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[/\\-]\\d{4}$');`